# How to set meteor ROOT_URL for mobile device deployment

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to deploy my meteor app on a iOS device using

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server myapp.meteor.com
```

but unfortunately every time meteor goes online it says

```
=> Started app on iOS Device.                 
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

How do I change this to point to my URL instead?

I looked around and people are saying to set these variables. My question is how and where do I set these variables?

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl
process.env.ROOT_URL
process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL 
process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL
```

Many thanks!

Comment: export ROOT_URL=value

Comment: did you try to set it in your meteor server code? like 

`process.env.ROOT_URL = process.env.ROOT_URL || "http://example.com"`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not connected to the remote server? I think this is how things are supposed to work.

Comment: Try logging into an account that only exists on the server and see if it works